# myArralist.contains(obj) always return false though myArraylist contain specified obj in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to check wether `mylist` contains a given object or not, where `mylist` is an `ArrayList` of type `myCustomClass`.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-java-arraylist-contains-method-evaluate-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add an instance of `MyCustomClass` to the list, and then check if it contains another instance of `MyCustomClass`, it will always return false, unless you override the `equals` method in your custom class. The equals method checks if another object is functionally equal to this object.

Make sure to override the `hashCode` method each time you override the equals method. `hashCode` should return the same value for two equal objects. Also, equals should be written so that it's symmetric: `a.equals(b)` if and only if `b.equals(a)`.

Check equals and hashCode in the [javadoc of `java.lang.Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Comment: thanks @berry120 ,@Jesper i override equals (obj) method and it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

You most likely haven't implemented `equals()` and `hashcode()` on `myCustomClass`. You need to implement them properly and according to contract, see [here](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html) for details of how.

Comment: should i overide the equal() method in mycustom class ?? istnt it property of list interface??? confused?? anyways thanks for qick reponse

Comment: @chrish Yes you should and no it is not a "property of the list interface".

Comment: @chrish yes, override equals on the mycustom class - and it's good practice to annotate it with the "Override" annotation (it's ATSIGNoverride, can't use the at sign there for some reason) so it's definitely overriden (the compiler will complain if you use the annotation and it's not.) There's no such things as "properties" in Java (not like in C# anyway.)

Comment: thanks @berry120 ,@Jesper i override equals (obj) method and it works fine for me