# How can i get the list of unselected elements?

Tags: java, list

I have two arrayLists namely `readAllNames` and anotherone is `selectedNames`.now i want to get the anotherlist which having the `unSelectedNames` .ex.

```
List<Name>readAllNames = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
List<Name>selectedNames = {"a","b"};
```

how can i get the:  `unSelectedNames` {"c","d","e","f","g"} from `readAllNames`?

without Using `remove()` And `removeAll()`

Comment: why `without Using remove() And removeAll()` ?

Comment: Try to use readAllNames.indexOf(object); object - element from selected names.

Comment: If remove and removeAll are not working properly it may be because your Name class does not implement equals / hashcode properly.

Comment: here incase  selectedNames having {"a","e"}means how can you use index ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> unread = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : readAllNames ){
    if(!selectedNames.contains(s))
        unread.add(s);
}
```

Comment: but Have to do override also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-java-arraylist-contains-method-evaluate-objects

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `remove()`/`removeAll()` you could always iterate through `readAllNames` and for each element check if it is `contains()`'ed in `selectedNames` and if not add it to `unselectedNames`.

But you *really* should use `removeAll()`; show us your `Name` class and we can probably tell you what's wrong (hint: read up on `equals()` and `hashCode()` semantics wrt. `Collection` operations.)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look at the sourcecode for `remove()` and use that?

Comment: bcz '@PostConstruct' method remove() and removeAll() not working properly.but those are working in junit test perfectly.i don't know the reason .

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your response.  remove() will definitely do what you want it to do.  If it's not working then it's an issue with your data or parameters.

Comment: This is probably because your Name class has not implemented equals / hashcode methods properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Name> unselectedName = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Name s: readAllNames){
    if(!selectedNames.contains(s)){
        unselectedName.add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<String> unSelectedNames = new ArrayList<String>(readAllNames);
unSelectedNames.removeAll(selectedNames);
```

You don't have to touch the original `List`, just the copy of that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Name>readAllNames = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
List<Name>selectedNames = {"a","b"};
List<Name>unselectedNames = null;
Collections.copy(unselectedNames , readAllNames);
unselectedNames.removeAll(selectedNames);
```