# How ArrayList contains method work?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, equals, primitive

I've a doubt about how ArrayList contains method works. Let's take an example:

```
List<String> lstStr = new ArrayList<String>();
String tempStr1 = new String("1");
String tempStr2 = new String("1");

lstStr.add(tempStr1);

if (lst.contains(tempStr2))
    System.out.println("contains");
else
    System.out.println("not contains");
```

it returns 'not contains'.

Another example:

```
List<LinkProfileGeo> lst = new ArrayList<LinkProfileGeo>();
LinkProfileGeo temp1 = new LinkProfileGeo();
temp1.setGeoCode("1");
LinkProfileGeo temp2 = new LinkProfileGeo();
temp2.setGeoCode("1");

lst.add(temp1);

if (lst.contains(temp2))
    System.out.println("contains");
else
   System.out.println("not contains");
```

It returns contains. So how does contains method works ?

Thanks

Comment: If you fix your example to call `lstStr.contains`, it *does* work. (There's no variable called `lst`.) I suggest you delete this question, and edit it then undelete it when you've got a *real* short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: the second part is a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-java-arraylist-contains-method-evaluate-objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You are adding your string to the list `lstStr`

```
lstStr.add(tempStr1);
```

but you are using `contains` method on `lst`

```
if (lst.contains(tempStr2))
```

Your idea of testing is correct, as `contains` internally uses `equals` to find the element, so if the string is matched using equals then it should return true. But it seems you are using two different lists, one for adding and another one for checking contains.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the relevant source code from `ArrayList` if you're interested.  As @user2777005 noted, you had a typo in your code.  You should use `lstStr.contains()`, NOT `lst.contains()`.

```
     public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o==null) {
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                if (a[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                if (o.equals(a[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) != -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the second part is a duplicate of: [How does a ArrayList's contains() method evaluate objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-java-arraylist-contains-method-evaluate-objects)

You need to override the equals method to make it work as you desire.

Comment: String is Java library class and has correct equals method implemented...

Answer (score 0):

in first section of code :

```
String tempStr1 = new String("1");
String tempStr2 = new String("1");
```

both `tempStr1` and `tempStr2` refer two different-2 object of string. after that String object that is refered by tempStr1 is added to the List by the `codelstStr.add(tempStr1);` .so the List have only one String object that is reffered by `tempStr1` not `tempStr2`.but 
`contains();` method work on `equals()` method.that is  `lstStr.contains(temp2);` return true if content of String object which is refered by `temp2` is same as the one of content of String object which is added to the `List` and return false when matching not found.here `lstStr.contains(temp2);`return true because content of String object temp2 is equal to content of String object temp1 which is added to `List`.but in your code insteed of `lstStr.contains(temp2);` it is mentioned as:

```
lst.contains(temp2);
```

Here you are using different `List` reference variable (`lst`) instead of (`lstStr`).thats why it return false and executed else part.

**in 2nd section of code `setGeoCode()` is not defined.**