# How to match an EXACT String in ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to match an **exact** `string` in an `ArrayList<String>`.

Currently this code will execute if `myArrayList.contains(wordImLookingFor)`.

```
if (myArrayList.contains(exactWordImLookingFor)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In summary, I'm looking for the code to execute when the entire String "dude" is entered, not just "d" or "du" or "dud".

Comment: contains must do exact match, explain its behavior more

Comment: I take the input from the user, run a onTextChangedListener to see if it matches, then run a method.

What always happens is it is executed right away.

Say "dude" is in my `arraylist`, when the user enters "d" it runs the code..

Comment: inspect your input `exactWordImLookingFor` before contains method

Comment: String wordImLookingFor = EditText.getText().toString().toUpperCase();

Comment: what are you trying to say with this statement ?

Comment: i do not agree with "Currently this code will execute if myArrayList.contains(wordImLookingFor)."

Comment: @skoll Why wouldn't it? That's literally the exact condition of the if statement.

Comment: no, there is not "exact" in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see if a string is in the arraylist try this:

```
for (String s : myArrayList)
{
    if (s.equals(wordImLookingFor))
    {
        // Run your code here
    }
}
```

or

```
if (myArrayList.contains(wordImLookingFor))
{
    // Run your code here
}
```

If you want to see if a string entered is a substring of anything in the arraylist, try this:

```
for (String s : myArrayList)
{
    if (s.contains(wordImLookingFor))
    {
        // Run your code here
    }
}
```

This should work for your example of `myArrayList` containing "dude" and the user inputting "d".

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the code to execute when the entire `String` "dude" is entered, not just "d" or "du" or "dud"

Comment: You said that backwards in your comment. You should edit it and the original question.

Comment: Man, I've tried the code but it still isn't working. (all of them)

I'm attempting to put this in an `afterTextChanged()`, do you think this could be giving troubles?

Comment: Figured it out, had to add this

`if (input.getText().toString().length() >= 1) {
                    input.setCursorVisible(true);
                    for (String s : list) {
                        if (s.equals(input)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: THANK YOU MAN! YOU ARE SUPER AWESOME!

Comment: Haha, any time! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Java's `ArrayList.contains()` uses the `equals()` method, which matches only exactly

[How does a ArrayList's contains() method evaluate objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects)

Comment: Are you suggesting use `myArrayList.equals(myWord)` because that does not work either :/

Comment: I am not suggesting that. I am suggesting `myArrayList.contains(exactWordImLookingFor)` already looks for only exact matches

Answer (score 1):

For this case it would best if you use a HashSet. HashSet has method contains and should return result in O(1)

Comment: Could you post an example please?

Comment: I dont think example is needed .. in your case you can replace your arrayList by  set (hashset) if ordering does not matter. Its all about ordering vs searching.  check this http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/07/difference-between-arraylist-hashset-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most graceful answer, but could you iterate over the array and compare strings?

```
for (String s : arrayList)
    if (s.equals(value))
        // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText);
String temp  = ed.getText().toString();
boolean status = myArrayList.contains(temp);
```

or

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText);
String s = ed.getText().toString();

for(String temp: myArrayList){
    if(temp.equals(s)){
       return true;
}
return false;
```

}