# Compare a value with all the values in arraylist in java

Tags: android

In my case Arraylist contains user define timings like{12:23,15:40,17:17...}.
how can i print message when system time is equal to user timings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a ArrayList's contains() method evaluate objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects)

Answer (score 0):

First make an array for this by below code

```
String s = "{12:23,15:40,17:17...}";
String newstring = s.replace("{").replace("}");

int size = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(newstring , ",");

String[] arrayString = new String[size];
```

Now Compare

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

if(yoursystemtime.equals(newstring.split(",")[i])){
Toast.makeText(context, "equal", Toast.Lenght.Short).show();
}
}
```