# Java - contains check all items in an arraylist meet a condition

Tags: java, arraylist

```
myArrayList = {"Method and apparatus","system and method for the same","drive-modulation method"," METHOD FOR ORTHOGONAL"}
```

How can i check if all the Items (myArrayList) contains a word "method" (irrespective of case)

boolean method return `true` if all the items contain the word, else its `false`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate and use contains. Remove the or conditions if you want case specific.

```
   public static boolean isListContainMethod(List<String> arraylist) {
    for (String str : arraylist) {
        if (!str.toLowerCase().contains("method")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @SURESH : how can i check for Sentence case i.e "method and apparatus"

Comment: @Prabu  `if (!str.toLowerCase().contains("method and apparatus")) {`

Comment: @SURESH: its always return false, but all the item have the exact sentence "method and apparatus"

Comment: @Suresh: now its working simple mistake in IF condition  (!str.toLowerCase().contains("method and apparatus".toLowerCase()))

Comment: @Prabu No problem. Everyone make mistakes ..happy coding.

Answer (score 49):

In ***Java8***, you can use ***stream*** with ***matching*** to simplify your code.

```
 return arrayList.stream().allMatch(t -> t.toLowerCase().contains("test"));
```

Comment: If you're using Java 8 please use the right methods. OP wants to check if every item contains the String. Therefore use `allMatch` instead of filter

Answer (score 2):

```
    public boolean listContainsAll(List<String> list) {
    for (String item : list) {
        if (!item.toLowerCase().contains("method")) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple loop checking condition, added white chars for avoiding wrong words as 'somewordmethod':

```
    boolean result = true;
    for (String elem : yourList) {
        if (!elem.toLowerCase().contains(" method ")) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;


 return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to check for the whole arraylist and return false if there is a string without that word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("I have the name");
list.add("I dont have the number");
list.add("I have a car");
System.out.println(check(list, "I"));
}

private static boolean check(ArrayList<String> list, String word) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
for(String s : list)
if(!list.contains(word))
    return false;
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` implements the `List` Interface.

If you look at the Javadoc for `List` at the contains method you will see that it uses the `equals()` method to evaluate if two objects are the same.

```
int tempCount = 0;
for (String str : arraylist) {
    if(str.conatains("method") || str.conatains("Method")) {
        tempCount++;
    }    
}

if(tempCount == arraylist.size()) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer is copy-pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2642709. Savi, you can't just copy other people's answers; at the very least you *have to* give a link back to the answer you copied.

Comment: What does equals() have to do with the price of beans?