# how to get all available Eddystone beacons

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

I'm trying to display all the available Eddystone beacons in my app.I have two eddystone for testing this app.when i open app,It's scann beacons and display duplicated values like attached image..i want to show both beacons sametime when i open the app (-57 beacon and -69 beacon ).I'm using below code.

i have initialize these Arraylist on top

```
    txpowerArray= new ArrayList<String>();
    urlArray=new ArrayList<String>();

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
               @Override
               public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device,final int rssi,final byte[] scanRecord)
               {
                     new Thread()
                       {
                           public void run()
                           {
                               RangingActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                               {
                                   public void run()
                                   {
                                    connect(rssi, scanRecord,device);

                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       }.start();

               }

           };


     public void connect(int rssi, byte[] scanRecord,BluetoothDevice device){

            List<ADStructure> structures =
                    ADPayloadParser.getInstance().parse(scanRecord);
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           for (ADStructure structure : structures)
            {

                if (structure instanceof EddystoneURL)
                {

                    EddystoneURL es = (EddystoneURL)structure;

                    Log.d("Eddy", "Tx Power = " + es.getTxPower());
                    Log.d("Eddy", "URL = " + es.getURL() );

                        clickUrl=es.getURL().toString();
                        txpower=String.valueOf(es.getTxPower());


                    txpowerArray.add(txpower);
                    urlArray.add("" + clickUrl);

                    Log.d("devicelist", " "+url+" "+txpower);

                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                }else {

                 }

            }
        }
    }, 4000);
```

[Duplicate beacons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYG9B.png)

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code stops the scanning as soon as the first beacon is found. Finding the first beacon triggers `onLeScan()` which calls `connect()` which calls `stopLeScan()`.

There's some other code before `stopLeScan()` so there's the chance (in a small time window) that the other beacon is also sometimes found and `onLeScan()` gets called again, but it's only a slim chance.

You should keep scanning for a while and only stop the scanning based on a timer. Then both (all) beacons have a chance of being found during the scan.

So find some other place for this:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
```

The code could be something like:

```
// Stops scanning after SCAN_DURATION milliseconds.
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mScanCallback);
    }
}, SCAN_DURATION);

// Starts the scanning
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mScanCallback);
```

(Also starting a new thread only to call `runOnUiThread()` seems counterintuitive.)

Comment: In your way scan only one beacon.then I have add handler to scanning for some time.then it display duplicate  beacons.how to prevent that?i have edit my question

Comment: Yes, the beacons may appear several times during a scan cycle if their advertising cycle is frequent enough compared to the scan cycle. So you should identify each beacon (maybe with the Eddystone-UID/Eddystone-URL or with `device.getAddress()`) and add them to your list only once. You could keep a list of recently seen beacons and avoid adding duplicates. Just update any data if the beacon already exists in the list. I don't know if the [answer about scanning iBeacons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952919/android-how-do-i-set-uuid-beacon-value-to-proper-textview/32986093) is helpful.