# Search through array in android

Tags: java, arrays

So, I'm trying to have my app search through an array where each object contains multiple values, like so:

```
public static String name;
public Boolean inUse;
public static Boolean covered;
parkingSpots[] spots = new parkingSpots[9];

 spots[0] = new parkingSpots("A1", false, false);
 spots[1] = new parkingSpots("A2", false, false);
 spots[2] = new parkingSpots("A3", false, false);
 spots[3] = new parkingSpots("B1", false, false);
 spots[4] = new parkingSpots("B2", false, false);
 spots[5] = new parkingSpots("B3", false, false);
 spots[6] = new parkingSpots("C1", false, true);
 spots[7] = new parkingSpots("C2", false, true); 
 spots[8] = new parkingSpots("C3", false, true);
```

What I want it do to is search to see if the spot is both covered and not in use, and then return the name of the first available spot with that criteria, so I did this:

```
 public boolean coveredSearch() {
    if (Arrays.asList(spots).contains(covered = true)) {
        if (Arrays.asList(spots).contains(inUse = false)) {
            return Arrays.asList(spots).contains(name);

        }

    }
```

But for some reason, running this method crashes my app. Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: What is the exception thrown? Can we see the stack trace?

Comment: I made very few changes, but now it seems to run okay. I also wanted to know, is this a valid method of searching?

Comment: This is not a free debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said you cannot use contains like that. Contains checks that an element is in a List using the `equals()` method.

Put this method in your ParkingSpots class. And call it to find your desired spot.

```
public String coveredSearch(List<ParkingSpots> parkingSpots) {
        for (ParkingSpots p: parkingSpots) {
            if (!p.inUse && p.covered) {
                return p.name;
            }
        }
        return "Cannot find parking space";
    }
```

Testing:

```
public class SpacesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ParkingSpots ps = new ParkingSpots("Dummy", false, false);

        ParkingSpots[] spots = new ParkingSpots[9];

         spots[0] = new ParkingSpots("A1", false, false);
         spots[1] = new ParkingSpots("A2", false, false);
         spots[2] = new ParkingSpots("A3", false, false);
         spots[3] = new ParkingSpots("B1", false, false);
         spots[4] = new ParkingSpots("B2", false, false);
         spots[5] = new ParkingSpots("B3", false, false);
         spots[6] = new ParkingSpots("C1", false, true);
         spots[7] = new ParkingSpots("C2", false, true); 
         spots[8] = new ParkingSpots("C3", false, true);

         System.out.println(ps.coveredSearch(Arrays.asList(spots)));
    }    
}
```

Output: C3

Also as said I recommend you rename ParkingSpots to ParkingSpot.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you put the method in the `ParkingSpots` class, then it needs to be `static`.

Answer (score 2):

Contains uses equals, internally. You're passing an assignment as parameter, guessing it would infer which property you want to compare in order to define equality, but that doesn't work this way. 
You question might be related to [How does a ArrayList's contains() method evaluate objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects).

What defines equality in this case, is your class equals implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks if there are *any* covered spots, and if there are *any* unused spots, but doesn't check if there is a spot that is both at the same time. You can't use independent `contains()` calls, even if you were using them right, which you are not (see other answers).

What you need is a simple search loop to find *a* spot that is both covered and unused, then return the name of *that* spot:

```
public String findCovered() {
    for (parkingSpots spot : this.spots)
        if (spot.isCovered() and ! spot.isInUse())
            return spot.getName();
   return null; // No unused covered parking spots available
}
```

Or, if using Java 8:

```
public Optional<String> findCovered() {
    return Arrays.stream(this.spots)
                 .filter(s -> s.isCovered() and ! s.isInUse())
                 .map(parkingSpots::getName)
                 .findAny();
}
```

Also, be aware that your fields are wrong. The `name` and `covered` fields **must not** be `static`, and the `inUse` and `covered` fields should be `boolean`, not `Boolean`.

Maybe it was just an abbreviation of the actual code, but `spots` should not be a field of `parkingSpots`. If it has to be there, it must be `static`.

```
public class parkingSpots { // Should be name ParkingSpots
    private String name;
    private boolean inUse;
    private boolean covered;
    // constructors and methods here
}
public class ParkingLot {
    private parkingSpots[] spots;
    // constructors and methods here, incl. findCovered()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the error is but your code is not going to work.

You have the following

```
Arrays.asList(spots).contains(covered = true)
```

This is basically the same thing as the following code.

```
covered = true;
Arrays.asList(spots).contains(covered)
```

And because `true` will never equals any of your `parkingSpots` instances it will always return false.

*Note on Naming*

By convention your class should be called `ParkingSpot` not `parkingSpots` it makes your code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you don't mind, could you point me in the direction of something I could try?