# Remove the duplicates in arraylist android

Tags: android

I have created the expandable listview.If i click the plus means that particular child name and count is add into the movielist.The duplicate childname and count is added into the list.I want to add the incremented count value and their name is added into the list.I want to delete the duplicate name and update the count for relevant name`

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        final Child modelChild = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);


        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                checkin_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(modelChild.getCount()>=0)  // set your count default 0 when you bind data initially
                {
                    int count = (modelChild.getCount()) + 1;
                    modelChild.setCount(count);
                    count1=count1+1;
//                    int s= Integer.parseInt(itemname.getText().toString());
//                    Log.d("s--", String.valueOf(s));
                   // count1=s+count1+1;
                    itemname.setText(Integer.toString(count1)+"items");
                   // viewHolder.txtView.setText(Integer.toString(count1)+"items");

                    Detailpage.item.setText(Integer.toString(count1)+"items");

                    int total = 50 * child.getcount();

                    String name = modelChild.getName();

                    Movie movie = new Movie();

                    movie.setcheckin_name(name);
                    movie.setcheckin_count(Integer.toString(total));
                      movieList.add(movie);
                HashSet hs = new HashSet();
                hs.addAll(movieList);
                movieList.clear();
                movieList.addAll(hs);
                 movieList.add(movie);

                }


                // set your other items if any like above
                groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().set(childPosition, modelChild);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

`

Comment: i have tried using the hashset already.the duplicate name get added after using that

Comment: @AbserveTech Dude i got your problem but last time when we discussed you said it resolved

Comment: please keep the relevant code and delete everything else @AbserveTech..!!

Comment: dont add to array, check if (array.contains(value)) then do not add..

Comment: plz explain clearly @MarkoNiciforovic

Comment: dude,last time i have solved using one way but its not useful for getting the total count value@Nisarg

Comment: @AbserveTech ok and like what do you want in next screen now?

Comment: In next screen i want to display the child item name and that particular count value(for checkout process dude)

Comment: @AbserveTech ok let me check

Comment: ok give me the possible solution @Nisarg

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have an array that has 1,2,3,4..

And then there are 2 new entries: 2 and 7 and code:

```
if (array.contains(entry)) {
   // in case of 2 we will go here and we do not want to add because it already exists
} else {
   // in case of 7 we want to add so we add following line
  array.add(entry);
}
```

So long story short, array lists have a method called contains which you can use and check if your array already has that element and by checking that you can avoid duplicates

Comment: if (movieList.contains(movie)) {
                        // in case of 2 we will go here and we do not want to add because it already exists
                        movieList.remove(movie);
                    } else {
                        // in case of 7 we want to add so we add following line
                        movieList.add(movie);
                    }

Comment: I have use your code like that now also duplicates added

Comment: do you understand my code? It is not possible that duplicates get added.. Also why do you remove?

Comment: your are mentioning the array as arraylist am i right?

Comment: yeah I do, this should definately work :)

Comment: Its not works dude

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic This is not working because Movie in not a primitive data type. In order for array.contains(movie) this to work, you need to 'Override public boolean equals(Object object)' function in movie class. Check the answer from ChristopheCVB here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects

Comment: if i do like this means 1st value only saved movelist next item value not saved in movelist