# Java to find out and avoid duplicate string

Tags: java

In my project I use employee bean list in the list empVal string value contain  `01,02,03,05` in the same I need to avoid in another string

i.e in first bean emp1.empval="01,02,03,05" and second bean emp2.empval=" 01,02,03,05".
So emp2.empval should not be allowed as bean value numbers are present in emp2. empval is already exists in emp1.empval.

```
pulblic class employee
{
  private String empVal;
  ......
}
```

my doubt is how to achieve it either using iterate or split to compare string or any other way is possible?

Comment: The content of your question doesn´t really make it clear what you are trying to achive and due to this it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: tip: [**`String::contains`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: I understand nearly nothing in your question

Comment: Are you trying to ask that "How to avoid same empVal in two employee object"?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the equals method and check

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof employee){
        employee emp= (employee) obj;
        if(this.empVal.equals(emp.empVal){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then before adding the elements you can check, also you can add the other variables you have declared in you class `if(emp!= null && this.empVal.equals(emp.empVal) && this.empVal1.equals(emp.empVal1))`

For eg: 
`ArrayList<employee> empList= new ArrayList<employee> ();
        employee emp1 = new employee ("a");
        employee emp2 = new employee ("b");
        employee emp3 = new employee ("b");
        empList.add(emp1);
        empList.add(emp2);
        if(empList.contains(emp3))
        {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No");
            empList.add(emp3); //Adding if that object is not present in the list.
        }`

Basically `contains` method will check if the object is present by internally calling the `equals` method.

For more information on `contains` functionality you can check the link [How does a ArrayList's contains() method evaluate objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects)

Comment: as a sidenode, `obj instanceof employee` already does a `null` check, so `emp!= null` is quite unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you @KevinEsche for the suggestion modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achive this by

```
 Boolean valueExists = emp1.empVal.equals(emp2.empVal);
```

Comment: I need compare every value i.e first val  01,02,03 and second val as 03,04,05 . 03 present in both the string

Comment: use string.split(",") in order to split the string and store in arrayList and then you can compare those.