# I have an arrayList where each element is an array of integers of length . How do i use .contains method here?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I know it is a bit confusing, but i basically wanna check if an arrayList of integer Arrays contains an array or not? I have added a code for more sense.

I was trying the following code. But .contains method doesnt seem to work when checking for an array. An alternative method will be very helpful.

```
int[] data = {1, 2};
int[] data2 = {3, 4};
int[] dataCheck = {1, 2};

ArrayList<int[]> megaData = new ArrayList<int[]>();
megaData.add(data);
megaData.add(data2);

if (megaData.contains(dataCheck)) {
    System.out.println("A copy has been found");
} else {
    System.out.println("No copy found");
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the ArrayList is checking for equality in the contains Method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects

Comment: *"How do i use `contains` method here?"* **You don't.** `contains()` uses the `equals()` method and Java arrays don't implement `equals()`.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me a way to accomplish this task then?

Comment: Write a loop, and call [`Arrays.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-).

Comment: Ah, sorry i am very new to java. Can you help me by writing the code? Solution for the above problem would help heaps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be:

```
boolean contains = false;
for (int[] element : megaData) { // iterating over the list
    if (Arrays.equals(element, dataCheck)) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (contains) {
    System.out.println("A copy has been found");
} else {
    System.out.println("No copy found");
}
```

Alternatively, you could write a method for this:

```
public boolean containsArray(ArrayList<int[]> listOfArrays, int[] array) {
    for (int[] element : listOfArrays) {
        if (Arrays.equals(element, array)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`contains` does not work in this case because the `equals`-method of an array only checks if the array-objects are the same, not if they have the same elements (cp. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777279)). And `contains` uses `equals`.

My recommendation is to use only `Lists`s instead of arrays. `List`s have an `equals`-method that compares the lists' elements. The first lines of the code have to be changed for this:

```
List<Integer> data  = Arrays.asList(1,2);
List<Integer> data2 = Arrays.asList(3,4);
List<Integer> dataCheck = Arrays.asList(1,2);
List<List<Integer>> megaData= new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

`Arrays.asList` is an easy way to create a list with fixed elements. `List`s are usually declared with only the interface `List` and not the implementing class like `ArrayList`. This makes it easy to use another `List`-implementation at a later point of time.