# How to check whether String already exist in Arraylist?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an app in which contain ArrayList of some String let suppose a,b,c,d and i have a String called pack. What i have to do is that i have to check whether pack is already exist in arraylist or not if not exist then i have to add it in arraylist. How do i do that

code:-

```
ArrayList<CBlackList> appsListDataSet;
 public void setAppsDetails(String pack) {
    if (appsListDataSet != null && appsListDataSet.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appsListDataSet.size(); i++) {
            CAppsModel appsModel = appsListDataSet.get(i);
            if (pack.equalsIgnoreCase(appsModel.getPackageName())){
                //Not to know what to do here.
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642709/3981656

Comment: use `yourArrayList.contains("pack")` method

Answer (score 1):

Use the `contains` method in an arrayList. If your arrayList contains only String and you want to check for String value itself, then just do

```
boolean isPackPresent = appsListDataSet.contains(pack)
```

this will work if your arraylist has the same datatype as pack and is not a custom object.

Comment: My ArrayList takes <CBlackListModel>

Comment: Then you need to implement the equals method for your class CBlackListModel. Check the link which is mentioned as the duplicate to your issue

Comment: where is the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects

Comment: I only have to check whether ArraList<CBlack> contain "pack" if found then break the loop else add it to db

Answer (score 1):

Try Some thing like this

```
if(appsListDataSet.contains("your String"))
{
 ///Action to be occur
}
```