# List<MyModel>.contains(MyModel) java is not working

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have my Class MyModel which contains:

```
private int value;

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

Now I have populated MyModel class:

```
private final List<MyModel> listModel = new ArrayList<>();
private Mymodel myModel;

 myModel= new MyModel ();
 myModel.setValue(1);
 myModel.setValue(2);
 myModel.setValue(3);
 listModel.add(myModel);
```

I want to find out if listModel contains myModel

```
listModel.contains(myModel)
```

I have made some search and I know contains makes use of the equals but I am finding the right way to find the solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's really no other way to do this besides implementing `equals`.  You should implement `equals`.

Comment: And a modern IDE will help you with implementing it properly

Comment: If you have one primitive field that can identify the MyModel uniquely that is an int id for example then you can get the list of the fields from List<MyModel> and search for myModel.id in it.

Comment: "contains makes use of the equals but I am finding the right way to find the solution" - implementing equals() for MyModel IS the right way to use contains() later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a ArrayList's contains() method evaluate objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-arraylists-contains-method-evaluate-objects)

Comment: The object always equals itself. You need only make own equals() if you make another instance (with new operator) with the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `contains` in `ArrayList` class, you'd see that internally it is using the `equals` method to find the object:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}

public int indexOf(Object o) {
    return indexOfRange(o, 0, size);
}

int indexOfRange(Object o, int start, int end) {
    Object[] es = elementData;
    if (o == null) {
       ...
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (o.equals(es[i])) { //calling overridden equals of the object instance, else it will revert to the Object's equals which simply compares the reference 
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So you'd be needing to create both `equals` and `hashCode` for your `MyModel` class. You can take the help of the IDE you are using to generate it for you:

As an example:

```
class MyModel{
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof MyModel)) return false;
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel) o;
        return value == myModel.value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The object (should) always equals itself! The original implementation `Object.equals(..)` is `this == another`. The OP do not change the original `myModel` object's reference, so `contains(myModel)` must work without make own `equals(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to check for contains is to override `equals()` method. If you check how contains method is implemented in `ArrayList` you can easily find it out.
`contains()` method will call `indexOf()` method which will return the index of a element in the list. If the index is greater than 0, then it `contains()` method will return true.

Lets look how `indexOf()` method is implemented.

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This means `indexOf()` method is just traversing through elements in the list and calling `equals()` method in your `MyModel` class.

**So there is no other way to check for contains without overriding `equals()` method from Object class**

Comment: The object (should) always equals itself! The original implementation `Object.equals(..)` is `this == another`. The OP do not change the original myModel object's reference, so `contains(myModel)` must be true without write own `equals(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following code, I have modified it and added Logs, now u can check output printed on the console:
I would suggest you check for the object by using equals().

```
class MyModel {
private int value;

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyModel{" +
            "value=" + value +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
final List<MyModel> listModel = new ArrayList<>();
    MyModel myModel;

    myModel= new MyModel();
    myModel.setValue(1);
    myModel.setValue(2);
    myModel.setValue(3);
    listModel.add(myModel);
    //here your myModel object has '3' value and list has [3], So this will return `true`
    System.out.println("myModel=>"+myModel.toString()+"-->List = "+listModel.toString()+",, CONTAINS. =>"+listModel.contains(myModel));

    myModel= new MyModel();
    myModel.setValue(8);
    listModel.add(myModel);
    //here your myModel object has '8' value and list has [3,8], So this will return `true`
    System.out.println("myModel=>"+myModel.toString()+"-->List = "+listModel.toString()+",, CONTAINS. =>"+listModel.contains(myModel));

    myModel= new MyModel();
    myModel.setValue(100);
    //here your myModel object has '100' value and list has [3,8], So this will return `false`
    System.out.println("myModel=>"+myModel.toString()+"-->List = "+listModel.toString()+",, CONTAINS. =>"+listModel.contains(myModel));
```