# Why can't this function add items to the ArrayList like it should?

Tags: java, function, arraylist

I'm trying to create a function that should add an item to an ArrayList IF it doesn't exist already in the ArrayList.

This is what I currently have.

Account Class:

```java
public Account() {}

public Account(String accountName, int accountNumber, double accountBalance)
{
    this.AccountName = accountName;
    this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.AccountBalance = accountBalance;
}
```

Bank Class:

```java
private ArrayList<Account> accountList;

public Bank() {
}

public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
    if(!accountList.contains(account)) {
        accountList.add(account);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Tester:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Bank bank = new Bank("qLOwyONvKsM58ZdV& &yo", Bank.BranchLocations.values()[0]);
        Account account = new Account("aucchQitgyzLV", 6329668, 479389.0);
        System.out.println(bank.addAccount(account));
    }
}
```

It looks like I can add empty accounts without any value but if given optional parameters of 3 values, (name,number,balance) it doesn't accept it. I don't understand

### edit;

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Account acc = (Account) obj;
        return AccountBalance == acc.AccountBalance &&
                AccountNumber == acc.AccountNumber &&
                AccountName.equals(acc.AccountName);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't accept it"  ? Also, calling `contains` doesn't make sense if you don't override `equals(Object)` and `hashcode()` in your `Account` object.

Comment: What you print is the result of `addAccount()` which is boolean. It will be either `true` or `false`. The `toString()` method you added is never called.

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, use a data structure that does not allow duplicates instead of one that does (i.e. use a `Set` instead of a `List`).

Comment: similar read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2642589/1004631

Comment: @Benoit I don't want the toString. i want a true or false if the account is added or not.

Comment: @Arnaud the account is not being added using the addAccount method, calling the .contain works if the account given is a account() with no optional parameters

Comment: @ImYoonah123  That's not the problem.  It's because the OP probably didn't override `equals` and `hashCode`  That should `always` be done, just to be safe.

Comment: To be very safe here, I would use a `Set<Account>` and just skip the check for `contains(...)`. But before you do that, read the comment given by @WJS.

Comment: I have overrided the .equals method. see above @WJS

Comment: Please show  `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods, the problem is likely in there.

Comment: @ImYoonah123  Can you please show your class implementation.

Comment: @ImYoonah123 For a little more information on why you have to override hashcode see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2265503/8359764

Comment: @WJS Done, looks like I edited the toString instead of equals method.. now it should be updated.

Comment: @deHaar and @ The Head Rush I do not want to use a set instead of arrayList because I don't know how sets work and I feel like ArrayList will be better for my project

Comment: @Yoonah123 your decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ArrayList.contains(Object o) [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

It means, to make your method work correctly, you have to implement the hashcode/equals method in the Account class.

I have created a mock implementation of your code:

**No hashcode/equals method defined -> Object class's default hashcode/equals method used which treats each new Object differently.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{


    static class Account {

        private String AccountName;
        private int AccountNumber;
        private double AccountBalance;

        public Account(String accountName, int accountNumber, double accountBalance)
        {
            this.AccountName = accountName;
            this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
            this.AccountBalance = accountBalance;
        }

        public Account()
        {
        }

        public String getAccountName() {
            return AccountName;
        }

        public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
            AccountName = accountName;
        }

        public int getAccountNumber() {
            return AccountNumber;
        }

        public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
            AccountNumber = accountNumber;
        }

        public double getAccountBalance() {
            return AccountBalance;
        }

        public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance) {
            AccountBalance = accountBalance;
        }       


    }

    static class Bank {
    private List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String inputStr = "";
    private int inputInt = 0;

    public Bank() {
    }

    public Bank(String string, int i) {
        inputStr = string;
        inputInt = i;
    }

    public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
        if(!accountList.contains(account)) {
            accountList.add(account);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            Bank bank = new Bank("qLOwyONvKsM58ZdV& &yo", 1);

            Account account = new Account("aucchQitgyzLV", 6329668, 479389.0);
            Account account5 = new Account("aucchQitgyzLV", 6329668, 479389.0);
            Account account2 = new Account();
            Account account3 = new Account();
            Account account4 = new Account("sgdgrt", 0, 0.1);
            Account account6 = new Account("sgdgrt", 0, 0.1);


            System.out.println( "account added: "+bank.addAccount(account));
            System.out.println("account5 added: "+bank.addAccount(account5));

            System.out.println( "account2 added: "+bank.addAccount(account2));
            System.out.println("account3 added: "+bank.addAccount(account3));

            System.out.println("account4 added: "+bank.addAccount(account4));
            System.out.println("account6 added: "+bank.addAccount(account6));

        }

}
```

> Result:
>   account added: true
>   account5 added: true
>   account2 added: true
>   account3 added: true
>   account4 added: true
>   account6 added: true

Which obviously not correct.

**If you would insert the following hashcode/equals methods into the Account class:**

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(AccountBalance);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + ((AccountName == null) ? 0 : AccountName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + AccountNumber;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Account other = (Account) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(AccountBalance) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.AccountBalance))
        return false;
    if (AccountName == null) {
        if (other.AccountName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!AccountName.equals(other.AccountName))
        return false;
    if (AccountNumber != other.AccountNumber)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

> Result would be:
>   account added: true
>   account5 added: false
>   account2 added: true
>   account3 added: false
>   account4 added: true
>   account6 added: false

So your method would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After your edits regarding equal, your code must be working as expected.

Instead of using `list` and checking for duplicates using contains, you could you `java.util.Set`. It doesnot allow duplicates.
If you want to retain the sequence of insertion then use `LinkedHashSet` instead. It retains the order of insertions and disallow duplicates. 
All you have to do is to override equals and hashcode.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class Bank {
private Set<Account> accountList= new LinkedHashSet<>();

public Bank() {
}

public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
    if(!accountList.contains(account)) {
        accountList.add(account);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is going on but I recreated your program and it works as expected. The problem may be with your bank branch logic.  I did not override HashCode() but it is a good habit to get into.

```java
    public class BankingDemo {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Bank bank = new Bank();
          Account account = new Account("aucchQitgyzLV", 6329668, 479389.0);
          System.out.println(bank.addAccount(account));
          System.out.println(bank.getList());
          System.out.println(bank.addAccount(account));
          System.out.println(bank.getList());
          account = new Account("new account", 29228, 29202.2);
          System.out.println(bank.addAccount(account));
          System.out.println(bank.addAccount(account));
          System.out.println(bank.getList());

       }
    }

    class Account {
       String AccountName;
       int    AccountNumber;
       double AccountBalance;

       public Account() {
       }

       public Account(String accountName, int accountNumber,
             double accountBalance) {
          this.AccountName = accountName;
          this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
          this.AccountBalance = accountBalance;
       }
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          if (this == obj) {
             return true;
          }
          if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
             return false;
          }
          Account acc = (Account) obj;
          return AccountBalance == acc.AccountBalance
                && AccountNumber == acc.AccountNumber
                && AccountName.equals(acc.AccountName);
       }
       @Override
       public String toString() {
          return "{" + AccountName + "," + AccountNumber + "," + AccountBalance
                + "}";
       }
    }

    class Bank {

       private ArrayList<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();

       public Bank() {
       }

       public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
          if (!accountList.contains(account)) {
             accountList.add(account);
             return true;
          }
          return false;
       }

       public List<Account> getList() {
          return accountList;
       }
    }
```